# Amazon S3 static website with custom domain showing 'IP Address not found'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have recently set up a static website using an AWS S3 bucket (scottreganchimneysweeping.co.uk). I have provisioned an SSL certificate through AWS, changed nameservers with my registrar to AWS route 53, created a hosted zone with route53 and also a CDN using cloudfront.

However, when I type the URL into Chrome, it loads for ages and then brings up a 403 error, IP address not found.

In route 53, I have created an A record with the alias for the cloudfront CDN, as well as the CNAME record for the SSL certificate and the default NS and SOA records. I'm not sure what exactly is causing the issue here but I am a total beginner with hosting and DNS etc so I desperately need help to get this website live.

Could anybody suggest where I have gone wrong here or possible diagnose using the domain name above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 means that the requester does not have permissions to take the action requested. You may need to either set the ACL of the bucket to public read, or the ACL of the items you want to be public read.

When a bucket is not set to be publicly readable, even if it is set up as a static site already, all missing pages will show up as a 403 response, so another possibility is that the default path is not set to the correct file, e.g. default pointing to index.html whereas you have main.html in your bucket at the root.

Comment: Thanks for this James. This was a matter of two factors. 1) The permissions as you mentioned above (I’d made a mistake in the bucket policy) and 2) The change of DNS records was still propagating. Thanks for your help!